# Pass checked checkboxes to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with my js code, when I check my boxes onClick() action, they check all of them but In Inspect element in section network I don't see that something happen.

```
         <table class="table table-striped grid-table" id="tableLabel">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Book</th>
            <th>
                <button type="button" class="checkall" onClick="checkAll()">select/deselect</button>
            </th>

        </tr>
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<cit.Models.getCheIdTip_Result>)Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.idtip</td>
                <td>@item.tipname</td>
                <td>
                 <div class="pure-checkbox">
                 <input type="checkbox" idtip="@item.idtip" class="checktip" checked="@(item.idemployee == ViewBag.idemployee ? true : false)" name="@item.id.ToString()" id="@item.id.ToString()" />
                 <label for="@item.id.ToString()"></label>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewData["idemployee"]" name="idemployee" id="idemployee" class="idemployee" />
```

And here is my js code, how can select all of them and pass to controller.

```
        var isChecked = false;
    function checkAll() {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (isChecked) {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].className == 'checktip') {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                console.log(i)
                if (checkboxes[i].className == 'checktip') {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
        isChecked = !isChecked;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you just used label in there and that make u not click on checkbox only. you must have a js or jquery for make sure what u checked and even did u. i will show and example of mine. i had same issue about that. I used custom checkbox and couldnot send it to backend

```
<label class="custom-chk">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

$('.checkmark').click(function () {
     $(this).parents('td').toggleClass('chked')
})
```

i used ajax for sending an array. Make an array from the checked boxes and send it to backend with ajax.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < $('label').length; i++) {
            if ($('label').eq(i).hasClass('chked')) {
                qrfid.push(
                    $('label').eq(i).attr('value')
                )
            }
        }
```

dont finish the brackets and use $.post or $.ajax(just in the click of the button u want to submit with)

you havent written how you will send the datas. so i suggested same way i did. it is up to you

Comment: that's not working in my solution,can you write example on my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<cit.Models.getCheIdTip_Result>)Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.idtip</td>
        <td>@item.tipname</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pure-checkbox" idtip="@item.idtip">
                <input type="checkbox"  class="checktip" id="@item.id.ToString()" />
                <label for="@item.id.ToString()"></label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

<script>
    $('.pure-checkbox').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('td').toggleClass('chked')
    })

    var wantedids = []

    $("#yoursubmitbutton").click(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $('.pure-checkbox').length; i++) {
            if ($('.pure-checkbox').eq(i).parents('td').hasClass('chked')) {
                wantedids.push(
                    $('.pure-checkbox').eq(i).attr('idtip')
                )
            }
        }
        $.post("your url", { nameofC#variable: wantedids, nameofC#variable : $('#idofelement') },

        )
    })

</script>
```

idk if your div would have the chkd class it could ruin your code. so i added it to td tag. but div is also possible to be done. you will send everything with ajax. and you wont need form tag, name attrs in tags.

and also i have seen u tried to say that check the box if the following condition is true. but you can use
@if

```
@foreach (var fenn in ViewBag.Fenn.Rows)
        {
            bool p = true;
            <span>@fenn["FennAd"]</span>
            foreach (var kfenn in ViewBag.QrFennInfo.Rows)
            {
                if (kfenn["FennID"] == fenn["FennID"])
                {
                    <label value="@fenn["FennID"]" class="custom-chk chked">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div hidden>@(p = false)</div>
                }
            }
            if (p)
            {
                <label value="@fenn["FennID"]" class="custom-chk">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            }
        }
```

mine was like that. i havent used english in here . i just used viewbag and asked it to use double for and 1 if for checking the checked sql datatable. i mean i had a table for lessons and a table for groups. and also a table for their combinations.

Comment: This not working for me, myb i would need to do something else, with jquery.

Comment: hope you didnot just copy and paste the parts i have shown for you :D. i just showed the second one for you to take the idea of using if and checked=" "